# Getting information from Exchange Server 2003?

Tags: c++, vbscript, active-directory, adsi, exchange-server-2003

In Exchange Server 2007 and later i.e. Exchange Server 2010,2013 , i have find all the information related to Exchange like, name of all the mailboxes and distribution groups using cmdlet commands as

```
get-mailbox

get-distributiongroup
```

All these I can achieve using Exchange Management Shell commands in Exchange Server 2007, 2010, 2013.

How can i retrieve all the data like mailboxes, mailuser, Message delivery reports, all email addresses on the server in exchange server 2003. And how to select only meaningful attributes.

For example:

get list of message that have subject like "Exchange server"

```
get-messagetrackinglog -messagesubject "Exchange server"
```

this gives me information about sender, receiver, and many more attributes of all the messages that have message subject "Exchange server" ,

How can i find this type of information in Exchange Server 2003. Could I use ADSI editor for all these information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WMI for this, for WMI please [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms876479(v=exchg.65).aspx). The message tracking log class [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa143739(v=exchg.65).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can't use ADSI against Exchange Server 2003 to retrieve this kind of data. Alternatively, you could look at articles about Microsoft Exchange Free/Busy architecture. Here is one:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd339218(v=office.12).aspx